# Django Ninja api call from inside a django view

Tags: django, django-views, django-ninja

I am just learning Django and Django Ninja API. I have created a simple Api to create and read object(s).

models.py

```
class Person (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

schemas.py

```
class PersonIn(ModelSchema):

    class Config:
        model = Person
        model_fields = ["first_name", "last_name"]

class PersonOut(ModelSchema): # Just to make it clear

    class Config:
        model = Person
        model_fields = ["first_name", "last_name"]
```

api.py

```
@router.post("/person")
def create_person(request, payload: PersonIn):
   data = payload.dict()
   try:
        person, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(**data)
    except Exception:
        return { "mesg": "Some error happened"}

@router.get("/persons", response = list[PersonOut])
def get_persons(request):
    p = get_list_or_404(Person)
    return p
```

views.py

```
def get_persons_view(request):
   
   persons = ???
   render(request,"personlist_template.html", {"persons": persons})
```

If I import the function api, then it returns Person Model object rather than serialized object in the form of PersonOut.

I wanted to use the api call in way that it returns the serialized form as being called through API url.
This way I am attempting to

1. avoid rewriting that serialization code again.
2. Also, I wanted to use in my template key:value pairs to generate a table for all attributes.

I found 2 methods for objective 2.

One is using Django Serializers. In this case I need to have separate method, if I am serializing single model isntance.

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", Person.objects.all())
```

Or using method `Person.Objects.values()` or another methods e.g. models.model_to_dict or writing custom DjangoJSONEncoder. But, that is just extra coding, when I have already implemented that in API.

I am assuming there is some straight forward to call that api function inside a view where the decorator magic of Ninja works. Just cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs you are looking for can be found here:
https://django-ninja.rest-framework.com/guides/response/?h=from_orm#serializing-outside-of-views

Inside your view, you can do something like this:

```
output = [PersonOut.from_orm(person).dict() for person in persons]
```

The output should now contain something like:

```
[{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'}, {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. Although this still means I need to manually add that serialization part, but still it is better as it will atleast give me the same dict/json as defined in Schema rather than using serializer or other methods and then aligning the code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can work for you

```
def serialize(schema_cls, queryset):
     items = [schema_cls.from_orm(i).dict() for i in queryset]
     return json.dumps(items)


...
persons = serialize(PersonOut, Person.objects.all())
```